# Why do my results appear to differ between ag and grep?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep, ag

I'm having trouble correctly (and safely) executing the right regex searches with grep. I seem to be able to do what I want using `ag`

What I want to do in plain english:

*Search my current directory (recursively?) for files that have lines containing both the words "nested" and "merge"*

Successful attempt with ag:

```
$ ag --depth=2 -l "nested.*merge|merge.*nested" .
   scratch.md
   scratch.rb
```

*Unsuccessful* attempt with grep:

```
$ grep -elr 'nested.*merge|merge.*nested' .
   grep: nested.*merge|merge.*nested: No such file or directory
   grep: .: Is a directory
```

What am I missing?  Also, could either approach be improved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `grep -lr 'nested.*merge\|merge.*nested'` or `grep -Elr 'nested.*merge|merge.*nested'` for your case.
Besides, for the latter one, `E` mean using `ERE` regular expression syntax, since `grep` will use `BRE` by default, where `|` will match character `|` and `\|` mean `or`.
For more detail about `ERE` and `BRE`, you can read [this article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html)

Answer (score 3):

You probably want `-E` not `-e`, or just `egrep`.

A `man grep` will make you understand why `-e` gave you that error.